# Why can I not query my ActiveRecord relation?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rspec

I have a relation on my ActiveRecord object in Rails ( 3) and having got a little rusty with AR I'm not entirely sure why I can't query it.

I have a `deadline` which wraps a date in a few other bits and bobs.

I have a `Task` which `belongs_to` a `deadline`. The `Task` also has a `:by_deadline` scope, which works if I query it directly with `Task.by_deadline( deadline )`. It looks a bit like this:

```
    scope :by_deadline, lambda{ |deadline| where("deadline_id = ?", deadline.id ) }
```

I have a `Channel` which `has_many` tasks.

I want to be able to find all `Tasks` on my `Channel` that belong to a particular deadline. I am currently working in a spec testing environment.

This works:

```
 result = []
 @channel.tasks.each do |task|
    result << task if task.deadline_id = @deadline.id
 end
```

I get exactly what I would expect.

However, I am confused by why I can't use something like:

```
 @channel.tasks.by_deadline @deadline
```

Or if not that:

```
 @channel.tasks.find( :deadline => @deadline )
```

Or at least:

```
 @channel.tasks.find( :deadline_id=> @deadline.id )
```

Or even:

```
 @channel.tasks.find_by_deadline( @deadline )
```

Those seem like they should do something, but all return nothing in my test, when called right next to the above block, which works fine.

I am guessing that this is something to do with ActiveRecord going to the database rather than using an in-memory collection, but what do I need to ensure that it works or am I totally misapprehending how relationships are supposed to behave?

Comment: Can you post the code for the scope? You can actually use where in this case.

Comment: I think your guess is correct - did you try to `@channel.save` and then calling the scope?

Comment: @UriAgassi I actually call `@channel.save` as soon as I have added a task... I wonder whether at any point the _task_ is being saved after I add a deadline. Hard to check right now- I guess last thing on Friday is a bad time to ask an SO question from the office :)

Comment: @FarrukhAbdulkadyrov edited it in.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see the error here, everything seems right. Did you try running the commands from console?

Comment: Not only can I not find the error here, but today when I run the same code it works. So some kind of transient error I managed to whip up somewhere probably on the fringes of my testing setup, I guess. Apologies for wasting everyone's time...